# ¿Cómo hago una consulta de todos los usuarios en una base de datos mongodb con spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Estoy intentando hacer la consulta de todos los usuarios de una base de datos MongoDB con Spring Boot. Aquí dejo el código que estoy implementando. Disculpen si es algo obvio, recién empiezo con esto.

[image: Respuesta de Postman]

Implementación en el controller

```
@GetMapping(value="/consultar", produces 
="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<User> getAllUsers(){
    List<User> xusers=ServiceApplicationimpl.getAll();
    return xusers;
}
```

Implementación en Services

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ServiceApplicationimpl implements 
ServiceApplication {

@Autowired
private static RepositoryApplication repositoryApplication;

@Override
public UserId createUser(User user) {
    String userIdDb = 
repositoryApplication.save(user).getId();
    log.info("Created sucessfully on mongoDB");
    UserId userId = new UserId();
    userId.setId(userIdDb);
    return userId;
}

public static List<User>getAll() {
    List<User> response=repositoryApplication.findAll();
    log.info("Consulted sucessfully on mongoDB");
    return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Coloca el código de RepositoryApplication, el trace del error completo y en texto para poder analizar el error correctamente, según lo que se ve pareciera que no se esta inyectando la clase RepositoryApplication.

Comment: Era exactamente mi error. Gracias!